# Month function and its understanding in Amibroker code

Tags: amibroker

```
me = Month();
me1 = Ref(me, -1);
MFC = me != me1;
BSMFC = BarsSince(MFC)+1;
```

Can someone help me understand this piece of code?

Comment: It returns the bar number since the start of the month. It's similar to DayOfMonth but instead of returning the calendar day of the month, it returns the bar number of the month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newmonth=month()!=ref(month(),-1);
```

Basically Is MFC (==newmonth) checking for change of Month ?